# Search and replace vulgar words in a text by using a text file containing all the bad words

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def check_offline(text):
    list_pro = open('full-list-bad.txt','r')

    content = list_pro.readline()
    for ligne in content :
        if ligne in text :
            remplacement = "*" * len(ligne)
            text = text.replace(ligne ,remplacement)
            print ligne

    return text

print check_offline("this is a  shit world " )
```

Comment: Do you have a *question*? Also you should read up on the Scunthorpe problem.

Comment: @jonrsharpe he doesn't work , the text in the result don't change ,

Comment: Then [edit] the question to explain that; give a [mcve].

Comment: i don't find how to edit My question !!!

Comment: You literally click on the link that says "edit", either just under the question tags or in my earlier comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution , i maked the content of the txt file in a list with split method ,

```
def check_offline(text):
list_pro = open('full-list-bad.txt','r')

content = list_pro.read()
list_content = content.split('\n')
for word in list_content :
    if word in text :
        remplacement = "*" * len(word)
        text = text.replace(word ,remplacement)
        print word
        print remplacement
return text
```

print check_offline("this is a adult world " )

> > > > > adult
> > > > >
> > > > > ---

this is a ***** world

Answer (score 0):

The `readline` method just reads one line.

Either call `readline` more than once, or just loop over the file object:

```
with open('full-list-bad.txt','r') as list_pro:
    for ligne in list_pro:
        ligne = ligne[:-1]
        if ligne in text:
            # do replacement
```

Sorry for the confusion, the edit to my code made by @GarryPolley changed it to only call `readline` once, but didn't change my comment saying that it needed to be called more than once :/

Comment: i tryed readline() in other code, he read line by line , i am on python 2

Comment: maybe in your _other_ code you call it more than once to read line by line, but in *this* code it just reads one line.

Comment: can you help me please, i am not a pro , i just want to find an answer